# Sort data of date time Using sort in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I want to sort my text file data using sort command.
My data are in below format.

```
01-03-17  10:30AM                 1367 data_03012017_10_30_02.csv
01-03-17  11:00AM                   32 data_03012017_11_00_02.csv
01-03-17  11:30AM                 7532 data_03012017_11_30_03.csv
01-03-17  12:00AM                 3442 data_03012017_00_00_02.csv
01-03-17  12:00PM                 9715 data_03012017_12_00_03.csv
01-03-17  12:30AM                 1753 data_03012017_00_30_00.csv
01-03-17  12:30PM                 5857 data_03012017_12_30_03.csv
```

Above is my file data. Please help me to sort this data. I am getting stuck in AM & PM data. Please help on this. Using `sort -n -t"," -k1.7,1.10 -k1.1,1.2 -k1.4,1.5` command data will sort by date but  not with AM & PM. Let me know how to do this.

Comment: First, show what you have done first. "Do my work for me" type posts that show little - or in this case no effort at all - rarely  get responses and often get ignored and/or downvoted.

Comment: @Takarii added command but it will work for time data not with AM & PM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting date field in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536368/sorting-date-field-in-unix)

Comment: @AsheshKhatri: Can you provide an input which does not work? i.e. may be in unsorted order

Comment: @Takarii updated data in question.

Comment: @AsheshKhatri, a better approach might be to convert your dates to something clearer and easily sortable, using ISO8601 at least for the dates, and 24-hour time. Conversion should be fairly easy from shell, but the method will depend on whether you're using GNU date or BSD date.

Comment: @Zlemini that commands not working with my issue, giving the same response from my commands.

Comment: @ghoti we got this data from FTP server, that data can not be modified, this is the main issue

Comment: @AsheshKhatri, you can modify it as you process it. See my answer for details. Also, if it's `syslog` that is recording the obsolete date format, you might want to consider migrating to something like [`rsyslog`](http://www.rsyslog.com/) which provides much greater flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert your dates to something more standard.

Assuming you're using mm-dd-yy (an old fashioned USA convention), you might do the following using the BSD date command in POSIX or bash shell:

```
$ while read d t s f; do printf "%s %20d %s\n" "$(date -jf '%m-%d-%y %I:%M%p' "$d $t" '+%F %T')" "$s" "$f"; done < input.txt | sort
2017-01-03 00:00:43                 3442 data_03012017_00_00_02.csv
2017-01-03 00:30:43                 1753 data_03012017_00_30_00.csv
2017-01-03 10:30:43                 1367 data_03012017_10_30_02.csv
2017-01-03 11:00:43                   32 data_03012017_11_00_02.csv
2017-01-03 11:30:43                 7532 data_03012017_11_30_03.csv
2017-01-03 12:00:43                 9715 data_03012017_12_00_03.csv
2017-01-03 12:30:43                 5857 data_03012017_12_30_03.csv
```

Or, split apart for easier reading:

```
while read d t s f; do
  printf "%s %20d %s\n" \
    "$(date -jf '%m-%d-%y %I:%M%p' "$d $t" '+%F %T')" \
    "$s" \
    "$f"
done < input.txt | sort
```

This uses the `date` command to interpret and reassemble your dates, converting them from your current format into something that sorts naturally. Note that by doing this, you avoid the need for ANY options for the `sort` command.

Tested in OS X and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in `unsorted.dat` you could use the following code

```sh
cat unsorted.dat | while read line ; do
   d=$( echo "$line" | cut -d" "  -f1-2 )
   s=$( echo "$d" | \
    sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)\(\s.*\)$/\3-\1-\2\4/' | \
        xargs -0 date +%s -d )
   echo "$s $line"
done | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -d" " -f2-
```

What it does is

1. Read the file line by line
2. Extract the date field from the first two columns into a variable `$d`
3. Change the order of the fields from MM-DD-YY to YY-MM-DD as recognized by the GNU `date` utility
4. Convert the date to seconds since 01-01-1970
5. Add the number of seconds to the line
6. Sort by the number of seconds
7. Cut the first field containing the number of seconds out.

Result:

```
01-03-17  12:00AM                 3442 data_03012017_00_00_02.csv
01-03-17  12:30AM                 1753 data_03012017_00_30_00.csv
01-03-17  10:30AM                 1367 data_03012017_10_30_02.csv
01-03-17  11:00AM                   32 data_03012017_11_00_02.csv
01-03-17  11:30AM                 7532 data_03012017_11_30_03.csv
01-03-17  12:00PM                 9715 data_03012017_12_00_03.csv
01-03-17  12:30PM                 5857 data_03012017_12_30_03.csv
```

Comment: Once you convert the dates into YY-MM-DD form, you can simply sort on them as strings, without the need to convert to seconds.

Comment: @tribble Converting to yy-mm-dd isn't sufficient. One has to take care of correct ordering of am/pm times